# What impact does object mutability have on scope in python?

Tags: python, scope, closures

The following (absurd but illustrative) code works as expected by mutating the list defined in the enclosing function:

```
def outside1():
    l = list('abcd')
    def inside(a):
        print "Before - %i: %r" % (id(l), l)
        l.append(a)
        print "After - %i: %r\n" % (id(l), l)
    return inside

f = outside1()
[f(c) for c in 'efgh']
```

This code also works showing that an immutable defined in an enclosing scope is accessible within the enclosed scope:

```
def outside2():
    t = tuple('abcd')
    def inside():
        print "%i: %r" % (id(t), t)
    return inside

outside2()()
```

However this fails with `local variable 't' referenced before assignment`:

```
def outside3():
    t = tuple('abcd')
    def inside(a):
        print "Before - %i: %r" % (id(t), t)
        t = t + (a,)
        print "After - %i: %r\n" % (id(t), t)
    return inside

f = outside3()
[f(c) for c in 'efgh']
```

Can someone explain what is going on here? My first guess was that I can mutate but not assign to enclosing scope, but I would have at least expected the *before* print statement to work given that the `outside2` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python detects the scope of names statically while compiling:  A name that is assigned to inside a function becomes local to that function.  So the line

```
t = t + (a,)
```

renders `t` local to `inside()`, and any look-up of `t` inside `inside()` will try to look up a local variable of `inside()`.  When the above line is exceuted, `t` does not exist yet, hence the error.

In Python 3.x, you can resolve that problem by explicitly declaring `t` as `nonlocal`:

```
def outside3():
    t = tuple('abcd')
    def inside(a):
        nonlocal t
        print("Before - %i: %r" % (id(t), t))
        t = t + (a,)
        print("After - %i: %r\n" % (id(t), t))
    return inside
```

All this is completely unrelated to mutability.  Your example using lists doesn't reassign the name `l`, while the example using a tuple *does* reassign `t`; and this is the important difference, not mutability.

Comment: "Python detects the scope of names statically while compiling" Thanks, that's the short answer; the py3k tip is a nice bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Mutability has no effect on scope.

The issue is that assignment to a variable not in the current scope creates that variable, while merely reading that variable does not.

Answer (score 1):

Marcin is right. Mutability has absolutely no effect on scope.

What you need to understand is, in the first example while you are "mutating the list" pointed to by `l`, you are simply reading the variable `l` and then calling some method on it (`.append()`). This is exactly the same as in the second example where you are reading the variable `t`.

In both cases, you are not assigning to the variable in the outside scope, simply reading it. Mutability simply means that you can alter the stuff pointed to by the variable, thus sharing changes in that fashion. But from the point of variables and scope, there is absolutely no difference.

In the third example, you are assigning to the variable `t`. That is the difference. Python 2.x has no way to assign to outer variables except global variables through `global`. Python 3.x has `nonlocal` to allow you to do this. Note that **mutability has nothing to do with it**: if you tried to *assign* to (rather than just mutate the object pointed to by) the variable `l` in your first example, you would run into the same problem:

```
def outside1():
    l = list('abcd')
    def inside(a):
        print "Before - %i: %r" % (id(l), l)
        l = [1,2,3]
        print "After - %i: %r\n" % (id(l), l)
    return inside
```